# Minimum and Maximum values of product of terms

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that each term in the sequence $x_1, x_2,x_3,......x_n$(n is even) is either 1 or –1 or 0. Let S represent sum
of product of terms taken two at a time i.e. all $x_i
.x_j $(0 < i < j ≤ n) then find the minimum and maximum values of S.

Comment: for maximum I am using all the terms as 1 so I get the summation from 1 to n-1 viz, n(n-1)/2 but for minimum I am not able to approach

Comment: @ajotatxe the maximum value is okay but for minimum value how do we find the solution

Comment: @ajotatxe do you mean $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that there are $p$ terms that are $1$, $z$ terms that are $0$ and $m$ terms that are $-1$. The sum is the number of products $(+1)(+1)$, plus the number of products $(-1)(-1)$, minus the number of products $(+1)(-1)$, that is:
$$\binom m2+\binom p2-mp=\frac{m^2+p^2-m-p-2mp}2=\frac{(m-p)^2-(m+p)}2\ge\frac {0-n}2$$
Since $n$ is even, the value $-n/2$ can be reached by putting $m=p=n/2$ and $z=0$..